# Zip.Suspect.MacroDoubleExtension-zippwd FOUND

Tags: php, server

Everey Time i upload my zip file which is containing my project .This error is come.

How can i upload my project to server .

Help me if you know how to resolve this problem.

Error message:

> Zip.Suspect.MacroDoubleExtension-zippwd FOUND

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Looks like some kind of virus scanner is running on your server and rejects those files. Talk to your admins.

Comment: @maxhb i have 3 different server. from all i am getting same error.

Comment: Looks like ClamAV anti virus software is blocking your file. Google for `Zip.Suspect.MacroDoubleExtension-zippwd` and you'll find some info.

Comment: @maxhb so how i stop this antivirus from blocking my file

Comment: This can only be changed by server admins. As far as I understand the error your files get blocked because you send password protected zip files. Try using zips without password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ClamAV scanner flags them because they ends in ".txt.html". Normally a file is either text or html, so that's why it's flagged as suspicious.

You may rename those file and then upload again. Otherwise you can upload file via FilezillaFTP account